# Server sent events not working after once in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

here is server side code for `get_update` method in controller

```
  header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Connection: keep-alive');
  ...
  $wait_time = gmdate('s', $query['max_wait']);
  echo "data: $wait_time\n\n";
  flush();
```

and javascript code is (in jQuery)

```
var source = new EventSource('get_update');
source.onmessage = function (event) {
    $('#total_logged').text(event.data);
};
```

This is nicely working in Chrome and even in Forefox. **But problem** is, its stop working **after one update in firefox** (on reload work once and after refresh complete, work twice. After that stop). Whats wrong here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was jquery issue in firefox. The above SSE code within `$(document).ready()` this function is not work continuously in Firefox. I turn out the code outside of this function and now working nicely

Comment: Did you called the function outside or inside `$(document).ready()` ?